# como puedo llenar varios gráfico y tablas con datos desde controller MVC5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

Hola estoy intentando hacer varias operaciones sobre mi vista .cshtml, los datos los  estoy enviando desde el siguiente método, desde mi controlador y funciona para llenar una tabla y un gráfico, pero estoy intentando llenar varios gráfico don diferentes datos y no funciona.

```
   [HttpPost]
public JsonResult VentaServicio(string año,string mes)
{
    ReportDmsModel model = new ReportDmsModel();
   var años = Convert.ToInt32(año);
   var meses = Convert.ToInt32(mes);

    model.VentaServiciosTallerList = _servicioReportesDms.ReportVentaServicio(años, meses);
    model.VentaServiciosTallerList2 = _servicioReportesDms.ReportVentaServicio(años);
    return Json(model);// si envió todo el model, es decir dos listas.

   // si envió solo una lista  return Json(model.VentaServiciosTallerList);         }
```

mi vista actual que funciona si solo le envió una lista del model en este caso le estoy enviando todo el model

```
@model MBC.Models.ReportDms.ReportDmsModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "VentaServicio";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
@Html.HiddenFor(P => P.VentaServiciosTaller.año, new { id = "año" })
@Html.HiddenFor(P => P.VentaServiciosTaller.mes, new { id = "mes" })

@*intente también enviarle un ViewBag

@if (ViewBag.VentaServiciosTallerList != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.VentaServiciosTallerList; i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(v=> v.VentaServiciosTallerList[i].asesor, new { id = "as" })
    }
}*@

<input type="button" id="btnGrafico" value="Dibuja">
<div id="tabla"></div>
<div id="container"></div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/highcharts/5.0.14/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/highcharts/5.0.14/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/highcharts/5.0.14/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnGrafico").click(function () {
            var mes = document.getElementById('mes').value;
            var año = document.getElementById('año').value;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ReportDmsTaller/VentaServicio",
                type: "POST",
                data: { año, mes },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (model) {
                    toastr["error"]('Atencion!Cargando Datos Espere por Favor');
                    var data = [];
                    $("#tabla").append
                    (
                        '<table class="display nowrap" id="dataTable" style="width:100%">'
                        +'<thead class="text-center">'
                        + '<tr>'
                            +'<th>Asesor</th> '
                            +'<th>Tipo</th>'
                            +'<th>Numero</th>'
                            +'<th>v_neta_total_rpto</th>'
                            +'<th>v_neta_total_mo</th>'
                            +'<th>v_neta_total_tot</th>'
                        +'</tr>'
                        + '</thead >'
                            +'</table'
                    )
                    for (var i in model.VentaServiciosTallerList) {
                        $("#tabla").append
                            (
                            '<table class="display nowrap" id="dataTable" style="width:100%">'
                            + '<thead class="text-center">'
                            + '<tr>'
                                + '<th>'+ model[i].asesor +'</th> '
                            + '<th></th>'
                            + '<th></th>'
                            + '<th></th>'
                            + '<th></th>'
                                + '<th>' + model[i].v_neta_tot +'</th>'
                            + '</tr>'
                            + '</thead >'
                            + '</table'
                            )


                        ///datos para el grafico tipo pie
                        var serie = new Array(model[i].asesor + model[i].descripcion, model[i].v_neta_tot);
                        data.push(serie);
                    }
                    DibujarGrafico(data);

                }, error: function (model) {
                    toastr["error"]('Atencion!No se  Cargaron los Datos ');
                }

            });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno finalmente lo solucione..

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Esta funcion abre una modal que permite ingresar los parametros del reporte (año,mes) y se los retorna a la funcion
    /// VentaServicio(ReportDmsModel model) 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult VentaServicioModal()
    { 
        return View();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Esta funcion  recive de la funcion VentaServicioModal() un objeto model (ReportDmsModel model) 
    /// Y retorna a la vista "VentaServicio.cshtml" un objeto (model) con que contiene los diferentes objetos del model compatibles con (c# cshtml)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult VentaServicio(ReportDmsModel model)
    { 
    var año = model.VentaServiciosTaller.año;
    var mes = model.VentaServiciosTaller.mes;
        model.VentaServiciosTallerList = _servicioReportesDms.ReportVentaServicio(año, mes);
        return View(model);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Esta funcion recibe dos parametros (año y mes) eviados de la peticion Ajax que se activa con un botos en la vista VentaServicio.cshtml 
    /// y retorna un objeto (Model) en formatos Json, que contiene varios objetos del Model entre ellos varias listas
    /// para ser utilizadas en diferentes tipos de graficos u otras funciones
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="año"></param>
    /// <param name="mes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult VentaServicio(string año,string mes)
    {
        ReportDmsModel model = new ReportDmsModel();
       var años = Convert.ToInt32(año);
       var meses = Convert.ToInt32(mes);
       model.VentaServiciosTallerList = _servicioReportesDms.ReportVentaServicio(años, meses);

        return Json(model);
    }
}

@model MBC.Models.ReportDms.ReportDmsModel
@using System
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "VentaServicio";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
@* los siguientes 2 HiddenFor capturan de la funcion VentaServicioModal() la cual abre una modal, los parametros año y mes que serviran para ejecutar 
    la funcion Ajax que esta al final de esta vista*@
@Html.HiddenFor(P => P.VentaServiciosTaller.año, new { id = "año" })
@Html.HiddenFor(P => P.VentaServiciosTaller.mes, new { id = "mes" })
@{
    //foreach en esta funcion es utiliazado el objeto Model retornado de la funcion VentaServicio() compatible con cshtml c#
    foreach (var ventas in Model.VentaServiciosTallerList)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(V => ventas.asesor, new { @Array = ventas.asesor, id = "asesor" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(V => ventas.v_neta_rpto, new { @Array = ventas.v_neta_rpto, id = "v_neta_tot" })</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
}

<input type="button" id="btnGrafico" value="Dibuja">
<div id="tabla"></div>
<div id="container"></div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/highcharts/5.0.14/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/highcharts/5.0.14/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/highcharts/5.0.14/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnGrafico").click(function () {
            var mes = document.getElementById('mes').value;
            var año = document.getElementById('año').value;
            //esta funcion ajax realiza una peticion al la accion VentaServicio del controller ReportDmsTaller 
            //(url: "/ReportDmsTaller/VentaServicio") y recive como respuesta un objeto Json (success: function (model))
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ReportDmsTaller/VentaServicio",
                type: "POST",
                data: { año, mes },
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (model) {
                    var data = [];
                    ///el siguiente for utiliza la respuesta de la funcion ajax la cual recive un objeto Json en este caso model 
                    /// y ya que este objeto tiene contenido varios objetos, selecciona el objeto VentaServiciosTallerList for (var i in model.VentaServiciosTallerList)
                    for (var i in model.VentaServiciosTallerList) {
                        ///se arma un array con los datos para el grafico tipo pie
                        var serie = new Array(model.VentaServiciosTallerList[i].asesor + model.VentaServiciosTallerList[i].descripcion, model.VentaServiciosTallerList[i].v_neta_tot);
                        data.push(serie);
                    }
                    //alete si exito
                    toastr["success"]('Atencion!Cargando Datos, Espere por Favor');

                    ///se le envian los datos a la funcion que ejecuta dibuja el grafico "DibujarGrafico()"
                    DibujarGrafico(data);
                },
                error: function (model) {
                    //aleta si error
                    toastr["error"]('Atencion!No se  Cargaron los Datos ');
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function DibujarGrafico(data) {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: { text: 'VENTAS POR ASESOR' },
            tooltip: { pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>' },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                        style: {
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Brands',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: data
            }]
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: evita los comentarios en el codigo, trata de que la respuesta este lo mas limpia posible, y por favor explica tu respuesta